# Video Classification CNN - F1 score get stuck while training the model

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, video-processing, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to replicate the[Large-scale Video Classification with Convolutional Neural Networks](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/deepvideo/).
I've already downloaded the frames divided homogenuisly in bag of shots. The train and test DataFrames that maintain all the infromations have the following structure:

|  | index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | train/-b5vDKaAd9o/bag_of_shots0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 1 | train/-b5vDKaAd9o/bag_of_shots1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 2 | train/-b5vDKaAd9o/bag_of_shots2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 3 | train/5smf0wPlLk4/bag_of_shots0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |
| etc | - | - | - | - | - | - |  |

With as index the counter, the path of the bag of shots location and the one hot encoding of all labels.

Now my Custom dataset class is:

```
class VideoDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, df, transform = None, t = 'single'):
    self.df = df
    self.transform = transform
    self.t = t
  
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.df)

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    if self.transform is None: self.transform = transforms.ToTensor()
    images_path = self.df.iloc[index, 0]
    
    if self.t == 'single':
      images = self.transform(Image.open(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}/shot{shots//2}.png'))
    if self.t == 'early':
      images = np.array([self.transform(Image.open(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}/shot{idx}.png')) for idx in range(shots//3,shots//3*2)])
    if self.t == 'late':
      images = np.array([self.transform(Image.open(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}/shot0.png')), self.transform(Image.open(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}/shot{shots-1}.png'))])
    if self.t == 'slow':
      if shots%10 == 0:
        images = np.array([self.transform(Image.open(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}/shot{idx}.png')) for idx in range((shots/2) - 5, (shots/2) + 5)])
      else:
        images = np.array([self.transform(Image.open(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}/shot{idx}.png')) for idx in range((shots%10) - (shots%10)//2, shots-(shots%10)//2)])

    y_labels = torch.from_numpy(self.df.iloc[0, 1:].to_numpy().astype(float))

    if self.t != 'single': images = torch.from_numpy(images)

    return images, y_labels, images_path
```

Then regarding train test split I have:

```
def spit_train(train_data, perc_val_size):
  train_size = len(train_data)
  val_size = int((train_size * perc_val_size) // 100)
  train_size -= val_size

  return random_split(train_data, [int(train_size), int(val_size)]) #train_data, val_data 

train_data_single, val_data_single = spit_train(VideoDataset(df=train_df, transform=train_transform, t='single'), 20)
test_data_single = VideoDataset(df=test_df, transform=test_transform, t='single')
```

The DataLoader:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 8
NUM_WORKERS = os.cpu_count()
def generate_dataloaders(train_data, val_data, test_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=NUM_WORKERS):

  train_dl = DataLoader(dataset = train_data, 
                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                num_workers = NUM_WORKERS,
                                shuffle = True)

  val_dl = DataLoader(dataset = val_data, 
                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                num_workers = NUM_WORKERS,
                                shuffle = True)

  test_dl = DataLoader(dataset = test_data, 
                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                                num_workers = NUM_WORKERS, 
                                shuffle = False) # don't need to shuffle testing data when we are considering time series dataset

  return train_dl, val_dl, test_dl
```

The custom AlexNet CNN:

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, stream_type=None, t_frames=[1,1,1]):
        super().__init__()

        self.stream_type = stream_type
        self.fovea = transforms.Compose([transforms.CenterCrop((89, 89))])
        self.context = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((89, 89))])
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((170, 170))])
        self.t_frames = t_frames

        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels*self.t_frames[0], 96, kernel_size=11, stride=3, padding=2), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
            nn.LocalResponseNorm(size=5, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.5, k=2),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2)
        )
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(96*self.t_frames[1], 256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
            nn.LocalResponseNorm(size=5, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.5, k=2),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        )
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256*self.t_frames[2], 384, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 384, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),            
            nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
        )

        self.MaxPool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)

        self.init_bias()  # initialize bias

    def init_bias(self):
        for block in [self.conv1, self.conv2, self.conv3]:
            for layer in block:
              if isinstance(layer, nn.Conv2d):
                  nn.init.normal_(layer.weight, mean=0, std=0.01)
                  nn.init.constant_(layer.bias, 0)
        # original paper = 1 for Conv2d layers 2nd, 4th, and 5th conv layers
        nn.init.constant_(self.conv2[0].bias, 1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.conv3[2].bias, 1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.conv3[4].bias, 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        if self.stream_type != None:
          x = self.fovea(x) if self.stream_type == 'fovea' else self.context(x)
          return self.conv3(self.conv2(self.conv1(x)))
        else: 
          x = self.transform(x)
          return self.MaxPool(self.conv3(self.conv2(self.conv1(x))))
```

The initial Model is the one that take as input the middle frame of every bag of shots

```
class NoMultiresCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, CNN, num_classes):
        super(NoMultiresCNN, self).__init__()
        self.CNN = CNN

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False),
            nn.Linear(in_features=(256 * 7 * 7), out_features=4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False),
            nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=False),
            nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=num_classes),
        )

        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.CNN(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        return self.classifier(x)
```

The architecture of the Train and Evaluate steps:

```
class CNN_Architecture():

  def __init__(self, model: torch.nn.Module, train_dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, 
    val_dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
    loss_fn: torch.nn.Module, accuracy_fn, scheduler: torch.optim.Optimizer, device: torch.device, save_check = False):

    self.model = model.to(device)
    self.optimizer = optimizer
    self.train_dataloader = train_dataloader
    self.loss_fn = loss_fn
    self.val_dataloader = val_dataloader
    self.accuracy_fn = accuracy_fn
    self.scheduler = scheduler
    self.device = device
    self.save_check = save_check

  def __save_checkpoint(self, train_loss, train_f1, epoch):
    data_path = Path('data/')
    filename = f'{self.model.typ}_checkpoint.pth.tar'
    print('=> Saving Checkpoint')
    checkpoint = {'state_dict': self.model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': self.optimizer.state_dict(), 'train_loss': train_loss, 'train_f1': train_f1, 'epoch': epoch}
    torch.save(checkpoint, filename)
    print(' DONE\n')

  def __load_checkpoint(self,checkpoint):
    self.model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    self.optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
  

  def evaluate(self, val_dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, epoch = 1, epochs = 1):
    val_loss, val_f1 = 0, 0
    self.model.eval()

    pbar = tqdm(enumerate(val_dataloader), total = len(val_dataloader), leave=False) #, desc='EVALUATION'

    with torch.inference_mode():
      for batch_idx, (images, labels, _) in pbar: # there is a _ to ignore the paths
        images, labels = images.to(self.device), labels.to(self.device)

        outputs = self.model(images)

        #loss = self.loss_fn(outputs, labels).mean()
        loss = self.loss_fn(outputs, labels)
        f1 = self.accuracy_fn(outputs, labels)

        #val_loss +=  loss.data.mean()
        val_loss += loss
        val_f1 += f1
        
        pbar.set_description(f'{self.model.__class__.__name__} EVALUATION Epoch [{epoch + 1} / {epochs}]')
        pbar.set_postfix(loss = loss.item(), f1 = f1.item())
        
      val_loss /= len(val_dataloader) # already calculate the mean of all loss
      val_f1 /= len(val_dataloader) # already calculate the mean of all f1

    model_name = self.model.__class__.__name__
    if self.model.__class__.__name__ == 'NoMultiresCNN': model_name = f'{model_name} - Stream Type: {self.model.CNN.stream_type}'

    return { 'model_name': model_name, # only works when model was created with a class
             'model_loss': val_loss.item(),
             'model_f1': val_f1.item() }



  def fit(self, epochs: int):
    results = { 'train_loss': [], 'train_f1': [], 'val_loss': [], 'val_f1': [] }
    best_train_loss, best_train_f1 = float('inf'), float('-inf')

    for epoch in range(epochs):
      train_loss, train_f1 = 0, 0

      # Training phase
      self.model.train()

      pbar = tqdm(enumerate(self.train_dataloader), total = len(self.train_dataloader), leave=False) #, desc='TRAIN'
      
      for batch_idx, (images, labels, _) in pbar: # there is a _ to ignore the paths
        # zero_grad -> backword -> step

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        images, labels = images.to(self.device), labels.to(self.device)
        
        outputs = self.model(images)

        #loss = self.loss_fn(outputs, labels).mean()
        loss = self.loss_fn(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()

        train_loss += loss.item()
        f1 = self.accuracy_fn(outputs, labels).item()

        train_f1 += f1

        model_name = self.model.__class__.__name__
        if self.model.__class__.__name__ == 'NoMultiresCNN': model_name = f'{model_name} - Stream Type: {self.model.CNN.stream_type}'

        pbar.set_description(f'{model_name} TRAIN Epoch [{epoch + 1} / {epochs}]')
        pbar.set_postfix(loss = loss.item(), f1 = f1)


      train_loss /= len(self.train_dataloader)
      train_f1 /= len(self.train_dataloader)


      self.scheduler.step(train_loss)

      if(self.save_check):
        if(train_loss < best_train_loss and train_f1 > best_train_f1):
          self.__save_checkpoint(train_loss, train_f1, epoch + 1)
          best_train_loss, best_train_f1 = train_loss, train_f1

      # Validation phase
      model_name, val_loss, val_f1 = (self.evaluate(self.val_dataloader, epoch, epochs)).values()


      results['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
      results['train_f1'].append(train_f1)
      results['val_loss'].append(val_loss)
      results['val_f1'].append(val_f1)

      print('Epoch [{}], train_loss: {:.4f}, train_f1: {:.4f}, val_loss: {:.4f}, val_f1: {:.4f} \n'.format(
            epoch + 1, train_loss, train_f1, val_loss, val_f1))

    return {'model_name': model_name, 'results': results}
```

The accuracy measure that I have chosen:

```
def accuracy(outputs, labels):
    metric = MultilabelF1Score(num_labels=len(LABELS)).to(device)
    return metric(outputs, labels)
```

Function to start the all computation:

```
def train_evaluate(model, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS):
  # Train model
  start_time = timer()
  history = model.fit(NUM_EPOCHS)
  end_time = timer()

  print(f'Total training time: {end_time-start_time:.3f} seconds')

  # Compare the results between train and validation set
  plot_loss_curves(history)

  # Evaluate model
  # Test the model in the Test Dataloader
  start_time = timer()
  result = model.evaluate(test_dl_single)
  end_time = timer()

  print(f'Total evaluation time: {end_time-start_time:.3f} seconds\n')
  print(f"TEST Results for {result['model_name']} -> loss: {result['model_loss']} f1-accuracy: {result['model_f1']}")
```

And finally

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 5
n_class = len(LABELS)
singleframe_model = NoMultiresCNN(AlexNet(in_channels=3), num_classes=n_class)
loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=singleframe_model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=True)
CNN = CNN_Architecture(model = singleframe_model, 
             train_dataloader = train_dl_single,
             val_dataloader = val_dl_single,
             optimizer = optimizer,
             loss_fn = loss_fn,
             accuracy_fn = accuracy,
             scheduler = scheduler,
             device = device)

train_evaluate(CNN)
```

I obtain these results:

```
Epoch [1], train_loss: 0.6415, train_f1: 0.0020, val_loss: 0.5625, val_f1: 0.0021 

Epoch [2], train_loss: 0.4761, train_f1: 0.0021, val_loss: 0.3569, val_f1: 0.0021 

Epoch [3], train_loss: 0.2507, train_f1: 0.0021, val_loss: 0.1271, val_f1: 0.0021 

Epoch [4], train_loss: 0.0718, train_f1: 0.0021, val_loss: 0.0188, val_f1: 0.0021 

Epoch [5], train_loss: 0.0107, train_f1: 0.0021, val_loss: 0.0018, val_f1: 0.0021 

Total training time: 124.898 seconds
Total evaluation time: 3.226 seconds


TEST Results for NoMultiresCNN - Stream Type: None -> loss: 0.0358263327473281 f1-accuracy: 0.0
```

[image: Model results]

As you can see I've used the nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() loss function and the MultilabelF1Score as accuracy score.
Even if I change the model the f1 score remain stucks while the loss continue to decrease.

Comment: Your loss_fn is defined in CNN as torch nn Module, but accuracy_fn is not. Does it make a difference if you change that?

Comment: You mean change the accuracy with other type of measure? The point is that this is a multi-label classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be... use 'patience'.
Try with many more epochs.

Comment: Yeah but I feel that there is some undiscovered bug in the training process, even if it appears correct

Comment: Negative I've also taken more frames and more videos but the f1-score remain stuck at 0.00205